# Proxy git commands to only one clone

Tags: git, dvcs

I've got a couple of processes which use the same git repositories, but they insist on treating them as separate things. That leads to me having a number of clones of the same repository under different local locations.

Is there any existing wrapper for git that would ensure I have only one repo with hard links? What I'd expect it to do is:

- On `clone`, check in `$GIT_CLONES_PATH` if a given url has been checked out already. If it's not there, clone to that location, then hardlink-clone to requested path.
- On `pull`, first pull in `$GIT_CLONES_PATH`, then pull locally.
- On `push`, push to the remote of `$GIT_CLONES_PATH` (to prevent conflicts after local push), then pull in the common location `$GIT_CLONES_PATH`.

I guess there are hundreds of edge cases I didn't think about here, so: does anyone know some existing project that does this?

Answer (score -1):

clone a local repo. If it's done from a local one, you should get hardlinks.

Comment: Thanks, but that misses the whole idea behind why I want to use it and the actually described flows ;)

Comment: Not sure why you would want to bring on all this complexity if cloning from a local repo would solve it.